# ASP.Net MVC C#: Failed to acquire token silently as no token was found in the cache. Call method AcquireToken

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-b2c, microsoft-graph-sdks

I am attempting to retrieve Azure AD user profile data via the Microsoft Graph API.  I have set up a small Visual Studio MVC app using code examples from various sources, primarily Microsoft.  In my ignorance, I thought this would be a fairly simple process.

I have browsed other similar cases on SO and have attempted to make use of suggestions from others but to no avail.  I have been troubleshooting this issue for four days and would greatly appreciate any assistance.

```
//  UserProfileController.cs
-- contains the calling method: var graphToken = await AuthenticationHelper.GetGraphAccessToken();
//  
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Graph;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security.OpenIdConnect;
using SSO_Test.Models;
using SSO_Test.Utils;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;

namespace SSO_Test.Controllers
{
    [Authorize]
    public class UserProfileController : Controller
    {
        private ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();
        private string clientId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ClientId"];
        private string appKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ClientSecret"];
        private string aadInstance = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AADInstance"];
        private string graphResourceID = "https://graph.microsoft.com";

        // GET: UserProfile
        public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
        {
            string tenantID = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst("http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/tenantid").Value;
            string userObjectID = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst("http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/objectidentifier").Value;
            try
            {
                var graphToken = await AuthenticationHelper.GetGraphAccessToken();
                var authenticationProvider = new DelegateAuthenticationProvider(
                (requestMessage) =>
                {
                    requestMessage.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", graphToken);
                    return Task.FromResult(0);
                });
                var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(authenticationProvider);
                var user = await graphClient.Me.Request().GetAsync();
                return View(user);
            }
            catch (AdalException ex)
            {
                // Return to error page.
                ViewBag.Message = ex.Message;
                return View("Error");
            }
            // if the above failed, the user needs to explicitly re-authenticate for the app to obtain the required token
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return View("Relogin");
            }
        }

        public void RefreshSession()
        {
            HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge(
                new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = "/Home" },
                OpenIdConnectAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
        }
    }
}
```

```
//AuthenticationHelper.cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory;
using SSO_Test.Models;

namespace SSO_Test.Utils
{
    public static class AuthenticationHelper
    {
        public static async Task<string> GetGraphAccessToken()
        {
            var signInUserId = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;
            var userObjectId = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst(SettingsHelper.ClaimTypeObjectIdentifier).Value;
            var clientCredential = new ClientCredential(SettingsHelper.ClientId, SettingsHelper.ClientSecret);
            var userIdentifier = new UserIdentifier(userObjectId, UserIdentifierType.UniqueId);
            // create auth context
            AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext(SettingsHelper.AzureAdAuthority, new ADALTokenCache(signInUserId));
            //added check point for verification purposes
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Check point #1");
            //GOOD TO THIS POINT
            var result = await authContext.AcquireTokenSilentAsync(SettingsHelper.AzureAdGraphResourceURL, clientCredential, userIdentifier);
            //ERROR MESSAGE:  "Failed to acquire token silently as no token was found in the cache. Call method AcquireToken"
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Check point #2");
            //app never reaches the second check point

            return result.AccessToken;
        }
    }

}
```

```
//ADALTokenCache.cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory;

namespace SSO_Test.Models
{
    public class ADALTokenCache : TokenCache
    {
        private ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();
        private string userId;
        private UserTokenCache Cache;

        public ADALTokenCache(string signedInUserId)
        {
            // associate the cache to the current user of the web app
            userId = signedInUserId;
            this.BeforeAccess = BeforeAccessNotification;
            this.AfterAccess = AfterAccessNotification;
            this.BeforeWrite = BeforeWriteNotification;
            // look up the entry in the database
            Cache = db.UserTokenCacheList.FirstOrDefault(c => c.webUserUniqueId == userId);
            // place the entry in memory
            this.DeserializeAdalV3((Cache == null) ? null : MachineKey.Unprotect(Cache.cacheBits, "ADALCache"));
        }

        // clean up the database
        public override void Clear()
        {
            base.Clear();
            var cacheEntry = db.UserTokenCacheList.FirstOrDefault(c => c.webUserUniqueId == userId);
            db.UserTokenCacheList.Remove(cacheEntry);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }

        // Notification raised before ADAL accesses the cache.
        // This is your chance to update the in-memory copy from the DB, if the in-memory version is stale
        void BeforeAccessNotification(TokenCacheNotificationArgs args)
        {
            if (Cache == null)
            {
                // first time access
                Cache = db.UserTokenCacheList.FirstOrDefault(c => c.webUserUniqueId == userId);
            }
            else
            {
                // retrieve last write from the DB
                var status = from e in db.UserTokenCacheList
                             where (e.webUserUniqueId == userId)
                             select new
                             {
                                 LastWrite = e.LastWrite
                             };

                // if the in-memory copy is older than the persistent copy
                if (status.First().LastWrite > Cache.LastWrite)
                {
                    // read from from storage, update in-memory copy
                    Cache = db.UserTokenCacheList.FirstOrDefault(c => c.webUserUniqueId == userId);
                }
            }
            this.DeserializeAdalV3((Cache == null) ? null : MachineKey.Unprotect(Cache.cacheBits, "ADALCache"));
        }

        // Notification raised after ADAL accessed the cache.
        // If the HasStateChanged flag is set, ADAL changed the content of the cache
        void AfterAccessNotification(TokenCacheNotificationArgs args)
        {
            // if state changed
            if (this.HasStateChanged)
            {
                Cache = new UserTokenCache
                {
                    webUserUniqueId = userId,
                    //cacheBits = MachineKey.Protect(this.Serialize(), "ADALCache"),
                    cacheBits = MachineKey.Protect(this.SerializeAdalV3(), "ADALCache"),
                    LastWrite = DateTime.Now
                };
                // update the DB and the lastwrite 
                db.Entry(Cache).State = Cache.UserTokenCacheId == 0 ? EntityState.Added : EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();
                this.HasStateChanged = false;
            }
        }

        void BeforeWriteNotification(TokenCacheNotificationArgs args)
        {
            // if you want to ensure that no concurrent write take place, use this notification to place a lock on the entry
        }

        public override void DeleteItem(TokenCacheItem item)
        {
            base.DeleteItem(item);
        }
    }
}
```

```
//ApplicationDbContext.cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace SSO_Test.Models
{
    public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext()
            : base("DefaultConnection")
        {
        }

        public DbSet<UserTokenCache> UserTokenCacheList { get; set; }
    }

    public class UserTokenCache
    {
        [Key]
        public int UserTokenCacheId { get; set; }
        public string webUserUniqueId { get; set; }
        public byte[] cacheBits { get; set; }
        public DateTime LastWrite { get; set; }
    }
}
```

As you can see, I have noted in the GetGraphAccessToken() method the error message:

> "Failed to acquire token silently as no token was found in the cache.
>   Call method AcquireToken".

I was able to isolate the AcquireTokenSilentAsync() method as the culprit by bracketing it with a pair of Debug.Writeline statements, the first which ran successfully and the second which did not.  This was verified by reviewing the contents of the VS Output window, as follows:

> Check point #1
>
> Exception thrown:
>   'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AdalSilentTokenAcquisitionException'
>   in mscorlib.dll
>
> The program '[13980] iisexpress.exe' has exited with code -1
>   (0xffffffff).

I really want this thing to work and I would much prefer utilizing the Graph SDK approach as opposed to using a REST API.

Again, I have been banging my head against the wall for four-plus days.  My head is okay but the wall is in bad shape.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have noticed that you are using ADAL. Would you consider using MSAL? If you can, I would suggest looking into [this MSAL sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/tree/master/2-WebApp-graph-user/2-2-TokenCache).

Comment: I downloaded and ran the sample with no issues.  Problem is, I am not ready for ASP.Net Core.  I was, however, able to glean enough from the sample to retrofit my .Net 4.6 app to take advantage of MSAL-based caching.

Answer (score 1):

If AcquireTokenSilent fails, it means that there is no token in the cache so you have to go get one via AcquireToken as in [this](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet/wiki/Adal-to-Msal).

You've tagged the question with "B2C" but is looks like you are using Azure AD?

Answer (score 0):

There are a full set of Authentication Providers for the standard set of OAuth flows that are now available so you don't have to use the DelegatedAuthenticationProvider any more.  https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet-auth   There are docs about how to chose the right Auth provider based on scenario here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/choose-authentication-providers?tabs=CS

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  I have migrated from ADAL- to MSAL-caching which has resolved the issue for me.